# Apache2 reverse-proxy multiple locations

Tags: reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, apache2

I am trying to configure a proxy for my local application (bittorent sync) using apache2 `mod_proxy_html`. I run multiple instances of the local app, each for a different user. To access the web interface remotely, I need to redirect the address

`sub.example.com/user1` to the local app listening on `127.0.0.1:8888` and

`sub.example.com/user2` to `127.0.0.1:8889` etc.

The local app has some hard-coded links to `/gui` that need to be redirected too.

In my latest attempt, I managed to get the proxy running for a single user like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sub.example.com
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /user1 http://127.0.0.1:8888
ProxyPassReverse /user1 http://127.0.0.1:8888
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8888 /user1
Redirect permanent /gui /user1/gui

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, I would like to extend the solution for multiple users and ports, i.e. something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName sub.example.com
ProxyRequests Off

<Location /user1>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8888
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8888
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8888 /user1
    Redirect permanent /gui /user1/gui
</Location>

<Location /user2>
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8889
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8889
    ProxyHTMLURLMap http://127.0.0.1:8889 /user2
    Redirect permanent /gui /user2/gui
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

which unfortunately does not work as I intended.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not defining an virtualhost by user, like user1.sub.example.com, user2.sub.example.com

You cannot define twice the same *Redirect permanent* in the same context (here only one virtual host)

Comment: I admit this is a nice and simple solution, but not exactly what I was after. In my case it does not matter much, but in other situations it might. I will wait a while before accepting your answer. Do you know, if there is a way to make the `Redirect permanent` dynamic?

Comment: You could use mod_rewrite (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but here defining the right condition to trigger the redirection could be difficult.

Comment: This is not the answer to the requested question